# How to view Jenkins job configuration as XML in the Browser

Tags: xml, jenkins, browser

Having access to a Jenkins job configuration via the UI, how can I view the configuration as XML in the browser?

Answer (score 10):

One can view a Jenkins job configuration as XML in the browser by appending `config.xml` to the end of the URL. For example, if you have the following URL to a Jenkins job `https://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/myjob`, append `config.xml`: `https://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/myjob/config.xml`. This also works for users who do not have write access to the job.

This solution was tested with Jenkins 2.138.

Credit for this answer goes to Terraform user `taiidani`, who mentioned this in the Jenkins provider documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/taiidani/jenkins/latest/docs/resources/job#template

Comment: It seems that some modern browsers like Firefox do not support xml version='1.1'. You may get an error: `XML Parsing Error: XML declaration not well-formed`. Is there any other option via API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the cli much more efficient and faster!

```
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkinsserver get-job nameofJob >
> myjob.xml
```

Then simply view myjob.xml in browser